# kdb+ replication of RDB and HDB

Tags: kdb

I am trying to figure out how to implement/configure replication of RDB and HDB of kdb+
How to configure RDB and HDB to have two instances with the same data on different hosts?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to have the tickerplant log location and HDB location cross-mounted and accessible from both hosts. Then the RDB instance on the second host just has to replay the tickerplant log as usual, and subscribe to the same tickerplant - but the important thing is to *not* have the second RDB do an end-of-day writedown. Its .u.end should just clear the data from memory.

The second HDB wouldn't have any special conditions that I can think of, however in order for the instance to automatically refresh/reload (and pick up the newest date slice) then the original RDB which is doing the write-down would also need to trigger the refresh/reload of this second HDB.

Comment: " Then the RDB instance on the second host just has to replay the tickerplant log" - I was thinking that replaying tickerplant log is the resposibility of tickerplant itself.

Can RDB trigger just tickerplant to replay the log without tickerplant?

If no how RDB can trigger just tickerplant to replay the log not affecting others RDB?

Does it mean that every instance of RDB will need instance of tickerplant?

Comment: The tickerplant does not replay a tickerplant log, only subscribers (.e.g an RDB) replay the tickerplant log. The standard approach for an RDB is to 1. connect to tickerplant to register subscription and determine current log count 2. replay the tickerplant log (completely independent of the tickerplant) up to the log count found in the first step, 3. Once log replay is complete the realtime subscription resumes from the time that the subscription was registered in step 1

Comment: When replaying, the RDB uses `-11!` which reads the tickerplant log from disk. This does not affect any other process (doesn't affect the tickerplant or any other RDB). Finally no - you don't need multiple tickerplants. One tickerplant can service many RDBs and subscribers

Comment: I should clarify on "it doesn't affect the tickerplant" - it does of course create an output queue in the tickerplant as it awaits the RDB catching up from the log replay before the RDB is ready to start draining the output queue and receive realtime updates. So it causes the tickerplant to keep this output queue but importantly it does not block the tickerplant. The tickerplant can continue serving other subscribers as normal. It would only become an issue if this output queue became huge and approached the memory limit of the tickerplant or box

Answer (score 1):

Couple of other approaches that you could try. Since KDB does not have a replication management system there are chances of data loss or data out of order on replicas. So you will have to think how to handle those situations.

One easy solution to handle those situations is to maintain sequence number for each update. In case replica detects missing sequence or out of order sequence, it can ask primary to send the data for those missing sequences.

1. **Chained ticker plant**:  You could try setup similar to chained tickerplant style. Secondary ticker plant subscribes to primary and then secondary setup run like a normal setup.
2. **Secondary RDB/TP subscribes to Primary RDB**: Secondary RDB or TP gets updates from primary RDB. Secondary HDB would work normal.
3. **Separate process for replication management**: If you want multiple replicas then it would increase load on primary if all of them connect to primary. Also, managing data loss scenarios would be difficult.

   Instead, you could create a separate process and all replicas will subscribe to this. Primary TP/RDB will send data to this manager service which can then take care of replicas. This way you can also keep all replica issues related handling logic at one place.

   Another benefit of this approach is this does not require to change primary TP/RDB services/logic to handle data issues. Manager service will handle everything.